# Using Google EMM how to block the user from formatting the device

Tags: android, android-management-api, android-usb, android-enterprise

We want to block the user from formatting the device. So we have created a custom policy with following options.

```
"factoryResetDisabled": true,
"safeBootDisabled": true,
```

This does not work when Policy is enrolled, as when we went to boot-loader menu we were able to successfully format the device. Also the custom policy were removed from the device.
Is there any approach via which the factory reset is blocked from Boot loader as well?

Answer (score 2):

There is no method that allows a DPC to block/disable fastboot and/or recovery modes on an Android device.

You may want to check [Zero-touch enrollment](https://developers.google.com/zero-touch/guides/customer/how-it-works) as a workaround for this. This will give you programmatic control over the devices. If the device is reset by any means, it will be brought back under management again the next time it is set up.

Answer (score 1):

Is your DPC running on device owner mode? If not, it won't work. You cannot forbid factory reset if your app is not the owner.

Comment: We are Using Google DPC in Device owner mode and Factory reset was blocked from OS Level. but still we were able to do factory reset from Device bootloader.

Device used was : https://androidenterprisepartners.withgoogle.com/device/#!/5111293132406784

Answer (score 1):

factoryResetDisabled greys out the Settings > System > Factory Reset GUI option.

If you want to nerf Factory Reset from recovery-ui, you need to also set frpAdminEmails.
This doesn't prevent reset, but does prevent the device being used after reset without first giving the device access to google HQ, and then logging into the device with an frpAdminEmails-whitelisted email address.

The user can still bypass this by entering fastboot mode and erasing the FRP partition.